# I am trying to utilize `prettier` for formatting certain types of files, but my `formatter.lua` setup does not seem to work, what could be the issue?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lua, neovim, prettier

I am new to `NeoVim` ecosystem. I set up my config based from the `ThePrimeage's` video. After that I tried to install additional formatting using `formatter.nvim` package for `NeoVim`.

This is how my `formatter.lua` file looks like:

```lua
vim.cmd([[nnoremap <silent> <leader>fm :Format<CR>]])

local util = require("formatter.util")

local function prettier()
    return {
        exe = "prettier",
        args = {
            "--write",
            "--config-precedence",
            "prefer-file",
            "--single-quote",
            "--no-bracket-spacing",
            "--prose-wrap",
            "always",
            "--arrow-parens",
            "always",
            "--trailing-comma",
            "all",
            "--no-semi",
            "--end-of-line",
            "lf",
            "--print-width",
            vim.bo.textwidth,
            "--stdin-filepath",
            vim.fn.shellescape(vim.api.nvim_buf_get_name(0)),
        },
        stdin = true,
    }
end

require("formatter").setup({
    logging = true,
    log_level = vim.log.levels.WARN,
    filetype = {
        javascript = { prettier },
        typescript = { prettier },
        javascriptreact = { prettier },
        typescriptreact = { prettier },
        vue = { prettier },
        ["javascript.jsx"] = { prettier },
        ["typescript.tsx"] = { prettier },
        markdown = { prettier },
        css = { prettier },
        json = { prettier },
        jsonc = { prettier },
        scss = { prettier },
        less = { prettier },
        yaml = { prettier },
        graphql = { prettier },
        html = { prettier },
        reason = {
            function()
                return {
                    exe = "refmt",
                    stdin = true,
                }
            end,
        },
        lua = {
            require("formatter.filetypes.lua").stylua,

            function()
                if util.get_current_buffer_file_name() == "special.lua" then
                    return nil
                end

                return {
                    exe = "stylua",
                    args = {
                        "--search-parent-directories",
                        "--stdin-filepath",
                        util.escape_path(util.get_current_buffer_file_path()),
                        "--",
                        "-",
                    },
                    stdin = true,
                }
            end,
        },
        go = {
            function()
                return {
                    exe = "gofmt",
                    args = { "-s", "-w", vim.fn.fnameescape(vim.api.nvim_buf_get_name(0)) },
                    stdin = false,
                }
            end,
        },
        c = {
            function()
                return {
                    exe = "clang-format",
                    args = { "-i", vim.fn.fnameescape(vim.api.nvim_buf_get_name(0)) },
                    stdin = false,
                }
            end,
        },
        rust = {
            function()
                return {
                    exe = "rustfmt",
                    args = { "--emit=stdout", "--edition=2018", vim.fn.fnameescape(vim.api.nvim_buf_get_name(0)) },
                    stdin = false,
                }
            end,
        },
    },
})
```

I have `prettier` installed globally on my system: `/usr/local/bin/prettier`.

When I try to provide a relative path to the prettier executable instead of just writing `prettier` it does not find the formatter.

I have default `prettier` configuration file in my project directory (`.prettierrc.json`)

*Note: I've tried other formats for config too, but without any results.*

*Note: Formatting for other files does work (`Go`, `Rust`, `C`). Only `prettier` seems to have a problem.*

*Note: I had `prettier` installed using `Mason` too, but it did not fix the issue, just changed the `prettier` path while executing the formatting (this command - `print(vim.inspect(vim.fn["systemlist"]("which prettier")))`)*

What can I do to successfully utilize `prettier` formatting in my `NeoVim` setup?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue. tried null-ls but moved away from it doe to its archiving.

I now use [vim-prettier](https://github.com/prettier/vim-prettier)

add it to packer using this. but switch out yarn for whatever you use.

```
use { 'prettier/vim-prettier',
        run = 'yarn install',
        ft = { 'javascript', 'typescript', 'css', 'less', 'scss', 'graphql', 'markdown', 'vue', 'html' }
    }
```

what I want to do now is change the key binding to `<leader>f` if a prettierrc file is present and default to the buff format if not.